# C# Reqex for new line followd by char and 10 digits

Tags: c#, regex, file-io

My issue is:
I have a file about 100 Mb that I've tried to read line by line and the do some processing. The performance was not very good. That's why I want now to change and read it in memory at once by using ReadAllLines() and then spliting it in some reports that are marked by a line containing T followed by 10 digits. Can someone help me with generating the right regular expression that I can use to split, I am thinking of something like:

```
@"(\n|\r|\r\n)[T](?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d)",
```

is this correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If reading line by line performance was not good, Regex will be much worse.

Comment: I think you should post the code that you used to read line by line. Let's have a look at it. May be we can help to improve it

Comment: *is this correct* Well, does it work? If so, then it is correct. That's for you to tell us, not the other way round.

Comment: 1) Read line by line, 2) write lines not matching `@"^T\d{10}(?!\d)"` pattern into the current list/array/file, once there is a line matching that pattern, start a new list/file/whatver. Make sure you initialize the regex before the reading block and use `RegexOptions.Compiled`.

Answer (score 0):

A split pattern for your case could look like this:

```
(?=\DT\d{10}\D)
```

[Code Sample](https://ideone.com/6wKDj7):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
class Test
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      String sourcestring = @"sdfso dadfjlsdfjksdjfkjsd
sdfso dadfjlsdfjksdjfkjsd
T1234567898dssdkfjskfjksdj
T1234567890dssdkfjskfjksdj
sdfso dadfjlsdfjksdjfkjsd
T1234567891dssdkfjskfjksdj";
      String matchpattern = @"(?=\DT\d{10}\D)";
      Regex re = new Regex(matchpattern); 
      String[] splitarray = re.Split(sourcestring);
        for(int sIdx = 0; sIdx < splitarray.Length; sIdx++ ) {
          Console.WriteLine("[{0}] = {1}", sIdx, splitarray[sIdx].Trim());
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on your context you are probably still better off reading a large file line by line and collection the individual reports/blocks in a List or the like as suggested by Wiktor. You could also further processing of the reports/blocks in parallel. I suggest making use of the StreamReader and StringBuilder classes.

**Sample implementation**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pattern = @"^T\d{10}\D";
        var re = new Regex(pattern);

        var result = new List<string>();
        var block = new StringBuilder();
        var fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\file.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (re.IsMatch(line))
                {
                    //store current block or hand it off to different process, etc.
                    result.Add(block.ToString());
                    block.Clear();
                }
                block.AppendLine(line);
            }
            // final block
            result.Add(block.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```